# CUDA: How do I store persistent data?

Tags: cuda

I want to store background image data on device in CUDA. Later while I read a new scene from a video source I want to send the new scene as a foreground image to the GPU and substract it from the background image. I don't desire to resend the background image to the GPU for every scene. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Store the background image in a device memory array (i.e. on the GPU).  Then when you read the foreground image use `cudaMemcpy` to copy it to another device memory array.  Then launch a kernel that takes the two device memory arrays as arguments and performs the image subtraction.  Should be simple.

Assuming you use default context creation and this is all running in the same CPU thread, you don't have to worry about doing anything specific to keep your CUDA context "intact" as Bart commented.  However if you do any CPU multithreading you will need to do some context management.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm using C# interface and bing it to a CUDA dll. Which GPU memory i must store it? I firstly thought to store in constant memory but I couldn't reached to it in other frame.

Comment: Constant should be fine, but it is only efficient if all threads in a block access the same address at the same time.  You probably want to use cudaMalloc'd device memory, and pass the pointer around, then cudaFree it when you are done.  If you couldn't access the constant memory in another frame then you must be destroying your context every frame somehow, which is bad.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example..

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    uint *hostBackground, *hostForeground; //new uint[]..
    uint *background, *foreground;
```

First initialize your background and foreground data..

```
    cudaMalloc(background, ..);
    cudaMalloc(foreground, ..);
```

then load background data

```
    cudaMemCpy(background, hostBackground, ..); //copy to device..
```

then read the foreground data

```
    while (applicationRuns) {
        readImage(hostForeground); //read image..
        cudaMemcpy(foreground, hostForeground, ..); //copy to device

        //operate on foreground..
        substruct_kernel<<<threads, blocks>>>(foreground, background, width, height);

        cudaMemcpy(hostForeground, foreground, ..); //copy to host

        //use hostForeground
    }
```

free them up

```
    cudaFree(foreground);
    cudaFree(background);
}
```

Here is a simple substruct kernel..

```
__global__ void substruct_kernel(uint *foreground, uint *backgroung, int width, int height)
{
    int idx = threadIdx.x + threadDim.x * blockIdx.x;
    int idy = threadIdx.y + threadDim.y * blockIdx.y;

    if (idx < width && idy < height)
       foreground[idx + idy * width] -= background[idx + idy * width]; //clamp may be required..
}
```

I do suggest using libraries for such simple operations. Blas libraries or Thrust library might be the options.